# How do I test a program made with Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Beginner question here. Let's say I have my program in Javascript and it's connected to a server. The goal of this program would be that once you right click on a document, it appears in the "Open With" tab. How would I be able to test that this works? How would i get it to appear within this tab? This is probably some dumb oversight on my part,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the codes that you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is [Connect apps to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#distribute_and_market_through_google_drive). To do that, your app must be a [Chrome app](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2500820?hl=en) and it must be uploaded on the [Chrome store](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish).

If you've done that, follow these steps:

1. Click the "My Drive" dropdown button in Google Drive.
2. Click "More" amongst the selection.
3. Click "+ Connect more apps".
4. A window will appear showing different apps. Type the name of your app in the Search bar.
5. Choose the app and click "Connect" button.

You're app will now appear in the Open-with contextmenu (right-clicking) if it is able to open your Drive files.